# Connect to another database adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to import some old mysql data to my site's postgresql db, but I'm having some trouble connecting to the old mysql db. I created a rake task to try and print the user's name from my old database, but I can't seem to figure it out. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
desc "imports old records to the new postgresql db"
task "db:import_old" => :environment do

  class OldDatabase < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.establish_connection(
      :adapter  => "mysql2",
      :host     => "localhost",
      :username => "root",
      :password => "",
      :database => "old_database"
    )
  end

  user = OldDatabase.user.find_by_user_id(1)

  puts "Hello, #{user.name}!"
  puts
end
```

But I'm never able to output the old database's data. Any suggestions? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would want to define a class for each underlying database, inheriting from ActiveRecord and then modifying the connection parameters.

Then, in your models you would inherit from these specialized classes, and not from ActiveRecord::Base

```
 class DatabaseCurrent < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.abstract_class = true
   establish_connection settings['database']
 end

 class DatabaseOld < ActiveRecord::Base
   self.abstract_class = true
   establish_connection settings['database2']
 end

 # in your Model definitions:

 class User < DatabaseCurrent
 #...
 end

 class OldUser < DatabaseOld
 # ... 
 end
```

With Rails:

http://blog.vishnugopal.com/2008/01/12/multiple-db-connections-in-railsactiverecord/

Without Rails:

http://idevone.wordpress.com/2010/09/26/multiple-activerecord-connections-without-rails/